# Disabling WSO2 Certificate Validation

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'm new to WSO2.

I'm using the ESB Console, and I'm trying to add a **WSDL-Based Proxy**

After entering the WSDL URL if I then try to **Test URI**, I receive the following error:

**Invalid WSDL URI (Unable to establish a connection)**

I'm not certain was the issue is, but I'm guessing that there is a problem with the issuer of the certificate.  I would like to disable certificate validation to test that theory.  So far, the only setting I can find is the following in the wso2esb-4.8.1/repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml file:

```
    <transportSender name="https class="org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSSLSender">
            ...
            <parameter name="HostnameVerifier">AllowAll</parameter>
    </transportSender>
```

However, this setting doesn't help.  (And it really shouldn't help since the actual host name matches the certificate CN)

Any ideas on what I can look for to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you see the WSDL using your internet Browser (with the same URI) ?

Don't you have a corporate proxy ?
In this case, configure it in WSO2 adding thoses properties in your transportSender conf :

```
<parameter name="http.proxyHost" locked="false">localhost</parameter>
<parameter name="http.proxyPort" locked="false">8080</parameter>
```

(update hostname and port...)

Have a look at wso2carbon.log

If you can access this URI and wonder if AllowAll works, you can try to configure WSO2 to trust this certificate : 
download it from your internet browser and
install it in ESB_HOME/repository/resources/security/client-truststore.jks with keytool