# In Wso2 how to connect to Https endpoint

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

In Wso2 ESB when I try to connect with Https endpoint. I get

```
`TargetHandler I/O error: General SSLEngine problem`

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
```

How to solve this and how to get the certificate for the endpoint

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disabling WSO2 Certificate Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26746859/disabling-wso2-certificate-validation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added the certificate and it's working

1) First, in the browser go to the HTTPS link you want to add a certificate, then in the browser address bar click on the view site information tab(i,e on the HTTPS ). Then go to description and then export it.

2) WSO2 will get the certification information from the client-truststore.jks. So, import the certificate to client-truststore.jks by the command.

```
keytool -importcert -file path\FileName.cer -keystore client-truststore.jks -alias "the endpoint or the domain address(like Https://..)"
```

After this configuration **PKIX path building failed** exceptions will be resolved.

3) Then in ESB_HOME\repository\conf\axis2\axis2.xml configure the parameter mentioned below.

```
<parameter name="HostnameVerifier">AllowAll</parameter>
```

After this **`javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem`** will be resolved.